# failure to invoke reverse on a fibonacci sequence in range-v3

Tags: c++, range-v3

I can't seem to make `view::reverse` operate on the first 10 elements (using `view::take(10)`) of the fibonacci sequence `v` generated using `range-v3`'s `view::generate`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/view/iota.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/generate.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/take.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/reverse.hpp>

using namespace ranges;

int main() {
    int i = 0 ; int j = 1;
    auto v = view::generate([&]()->int{int tmp = i; i += j; std::swap(i, j); return tmp;}); // fibonacci
    std::cout << (v | view::take(10) | view::reverse) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error (followed by a lot more template-related output):

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'void')
     std::cout << (v | view::take(10) | view::reverse) << '\n';
```

However, if I use `view::iota` to create `v`, e.g.,

```
 auto v = view::iota(20);
```

I get no error and the expected output.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`view::generate` produced an Input range. You can't reverse an Input range. That requires Bidirectional. `view::iota` on the other hand produces RandomAccess ranges, which can be reversed.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.